# How to tell IntelliJ Idea 12+ to use test Maven profile when running any junit test

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, intellij-idea

In previous versions of Idea, if I had the "development" or "production" Maven profiles checked, whenever I ran my unit tests, IntelliJ IDEA did not actually use these profiles. Instead, it didn't use any of them.

Since I am developing a Spring-based application, I use 3 profiles to configure various things, but mostly my `applicationContext.xml`. Whenever profiles were not used, because the property syntax was the same, Spring would conveniently fall back to `applicationContext.properties` when a Maven profile was not used to replace the values in my application context.

But with newer versions of IntelliJ, this fallback mechanism no longer happens. If 'production' is checked under the Maven tab in IntelliJ IDEA, then IDEA will actually use that profile whenever I run my unit tests. This means that before I run my unit tests, I have to ALWAYS make sure to both clean the project and check the Maven profile I have selected, which frankly adds a lot of overhead when I need to switch back and forth between "test" and "development"... and god forbid my dbunit tests start overwriting the "development" database because the wrong profile was actually selected!

Now, I'm a pretty lazy developer. I like my IDE to be smart enough to always use the "test" profile whenever I run my unit tests, even if "production" or "development" is selected. How can I tell IntelliJ IDEA to do just that? It used to do just that in older versions of IDEA, and I want to get the same behaviour - it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the default test configuration (for me that's junit) you can set an environment variable, for example RUNNING_TESTS=true. Then you can have your test profile automatically activate when that variable is present (there is a reference to that on the [sonatype maven doc page](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-activation.html)).

Comment: I am not sure I understand... is it the `<property>` element in that documentation? I tried your suggestion, but it does not work. IDEA continues to use the selected profile.

Even using `env.RUNNING_TESTS` also does not work.

Comment: Maybe I am going about this the wrong way. Can I instead have a specific maven goal, like tomcat:run, use a development profile and keep test selected in IntelliJ? Maybe the inverse will be more achievable?

Comment: @Engineer Dollery: are you sure that'll work? Please correct me if I'm wrong, but that works if maven is used to run the tests "mvn ... test", which I don't think Intellij does.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ 14 this does not happen, i.e. by default maven profiles are not passed to tests.

But, if you need that, an option in Settings -> Maven -> Running Tests let you enable passing of argLine/systemPropertyVariables/environmentVariables to unit tests.